# socketio.client listen to server

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, flask-socketio

How to listen to server with `socket.io-client` inside React framework on node.js ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);

    socket.on('ctime', function (data) {
        console.log('ctime: ' , data)
    })
})
```

flask server emits msg:

```
@socketio.on('time')
def ctime():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    send(current_time)

while True:
    ctime()
    time.sleep(1)
```

what is wrong ? Client should listen and consume messages send by flask server

Comment: Why is the `ctime()` function decorated as a Socket.IO event? I don't see any code in the client that emits a `time` event.

Answer (score 1):

The socket inside the Client is listening for a `"ctime"` event to be emitted by the Server. The Server is listening for a `"time"` event to be emitted by the Client, then sending a `"message"` event.

Try changing the `"ctime"` in the Client to `"message"`, or change the `send(current_time)` function in the Server to `emit('ctime', current_time)`

I've never used flask before, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: still doesnt work, if I use `emit('ctime', current_time)` in flask I see in debug mode that only two messages have been send instead of using inf loop

Comment: @Qbik Is the client not receiving anything? Or is it just not running on an inf loop?